# Creating a method that generates all permutations of string in kotlin using recursion

Tags: kotlin, recursion

trying to write some code that generates all permutations of an input string as a recursion 
exercise but can't figure out why I get a stack overflow error.

```
fun main() {
    println(subSet(listOf("abcd")))
}

fun subSet(s: List<String>): List<String>{
    return listOf<String>() + createSubSets(s)
}

fun createSubSets(s: List<String>): List<String>{
    if(s.isEmpty()){
        return listOf()
    }
    return s.mapIndexed{i, elem ->
        elem + createSubSets(s.drop(i))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another example:

```kotlin
fun String.permute(result: String = ""): List<String> =
    if (isEmpty()) listOf(result) else flatMapIndexed { i, c -> removeRange(i, i + 1).permute(result + c) }

fun main() {
    println("abc".permute()) // [abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement leads to infinite recursion:

```
return s.mapIndexed { i, elem ->
    elem + createSubSets(s.drop(i))
}
```

In it, the first iteration has the `i` value of `0` (with the `elem` being the character at index `0`), and the recursive call `createSubSets(s.drop(i))` is equivalent to `createSubSets(s)`, because dropping zero characters from a string returns the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function is not safe. It iterates forever, keeps adding to the stack and that's why you're getting a stack overflow.

Apart from fixing your algorithm, you can do two things to improve the situation:

1. Add an exit condition to make the function exit eventually.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println(subSet(listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")))
}

fun subSet(s: List<String>): List<String>{
    return createSubSets(s, 0)
}

fun createSubSets(s: List<String>, index: Int): List<String> {
    if (index > s.lastIndex) {
        return emptyList()
    }
    val otherElements = s.subList(0, index) + s.subList(index + 1, s.size)
    val element = s[index]
    return otherElements.map { element + it } + createSubSets(s, index + 1)
}

// [ab, ac, ad, ba, bc, bd, ca, cb, cd, da, db, dc]
```

2. Make the function [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) so that even with long strings it won't stack overflow.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println(subSet(listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")))
}

fun subSet(s: List<String>): List<String>{
    return createSubSets(s, 0, emptyList())
}

tailrec fun createSubSets(s: List<String>, index: Int, carryOn: List<String>): List<String> {
    if (index > s.lastIndex) {
        return carryOn
    }
    val otherElements = s.subList(0, index) + s.subList(index + 1, s.size)
    val element = s[index]
    return createSubSets(s, index + 1, carryOn + otherElements.map { element + it })
}

// [ab, ac, ad, ba, bc, bd, ca, cb, cd, da, db, dc]
```

Notice that the tail-recursive version always calls itself as the last thing. Specifically, it doesn't perform any operations on the result of calling itself. That's why it has to carry on the result to the next call, but that is also why it's stack safe.

Finally, notice that you don't need recursion at all to solve this problem:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println(subSet(listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")))
}

fun subSet(s: List<String>): List<String>{
    return createSubSets(s)
}

fun createSubSets(s: List<String>): List<String> {
    return s.mapIndexed { i, element ->
        val otherElements = s.subList(0, i) + s.subList(i + 1, s.size)

        otherElements.map { element + it }
    }.flatten()
}

// [ab, ac, ad, ba, bc, bd, ca, cb, cd, da, db, dc]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main() {
permutations("abcd","")   }
                                         
fun permutations(str:String, storedString: String){
if(str.length == 1)
    println(storedString+str)
else
for(i in str.indices)
    permutations(str.removeRange(i,i+1),storedString+str[i])}
```

Comment: You need to explain your code a little. Any explanation for your code would make your answer more useful.

Comment: this function iterate through the input string "str" , every iterate it will take the char at current index and add it to the "storedString" and recall itself for the rest of the string str, thus when str contain just one character we will have got one permutation so it will print it.